# "USB Connected" constantly flashing on screen

Tags: samsung-galaxy-s, usb

The USB connection keeps coming up on the top bar of my Samsung Galaxy S. It wears down the battery and the phone turns itself off randomly, sometimes its hard to get it to turn back on, I have tried connecting the USB cable to the computer then disconnecting which did nothing.

Can someone help?

Comment: Try different USB cables and different ports (on you computer) or even different computers. I had a similar problem (with a different phone) but only with a specific USB hub. Using a different USB port on my computer made the problem go away.

Answer (score 3):

Your usb port is bad - this is a hardware issue. Take the phone in for warranty service.

Edit: I had this happen on my Nexus S as it came out of the box today. I flashed the latest stock ROM, then re-installed CyanogenMod over top (and restored my data). It seems to be a *little* less flaky. You may not be able to do anything of the sort, but it may help others.

Comment: this could also be caused by a cheap or bad cable. I have a cable that I bought that doesn't seem to fit perfect and if i move the cable/phone the littlest bit, it "unplugs", then plugs back in.

Comment: His phone is likely no longer under warranty. I'd suggest, just in case, doing a factory reset. If that doesn't resolve it, your phone is likely on the road to total failure. Random power-offs signal kernel panics (CPU faults - unfixable) or damage to the components which deliver power to the phone from the battery. Either way, the outlook for your phone isn't great.

Comment: I assumed, Ryan Conrad, that OP did not have a cable plugged in.

Answer (score 1):

I have one thing to say. Before even concluding it as a hardware issue, you can do one more thing.

Go to `Settings -> Privacy -> Settings Reset -> Reset Phone`

It doesn't remove any personal data on the phone and resets the Settings only.

The phone restarts itself. Now plug in your Cable to the PC and see if the same issue continues to happen. If it happens again then it is purely Hardware issue.

Comment: resetting my Sony Z2 has resolved that problem